# How to sum up the values and also cast it to varchar so that I can get output in JSON format in SQL server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, json, casting

I want to sum up the values of Revenue and group it by ProductName. I have used the following way. But I cannot sum up the values and cast it to varchar at the same time as I cant get the result in JSON format only if I cast it to varchar. 
Here is my query

```
select '[' + STUFF(( select ',{"id":' + cast(id as varchar(max)) + ',"ProductName":"' + ProductName + '"' + ',"Revenue":'
```

+ cast(Revenue as varchar(max)) + ',"InYear":' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), InYear, 111) +'}'
        from dummyRevenueData where InYear>='2014/01/01' and InYear<='2016/01/01' 
 for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') + ']'

The above query results:

```
[{"id":2,"ProductName":"P1","Revenue":700,"InYear":2014/01/01},{"id":3,"ProductName":"p1","Revenue":800,"InYear":2015/01/01},{"id":4,"ProductName":"p1","Revenue":900,"InYear":2016/01/01},{"id":6,"ProductName":"P2","Revenue":600,"InYear":2014/01/01},{"id":7,"ProductName":"P2","Revenue":200,"InYear":2015/01/01},{"id":8,"ProductName":"P2","Revenue":400,"InYear":2016/01/01},{"id":10,"ProductName":"p3","Revenue":100,"InYear":2014/01/01},{"id":11,"ProductName":"p3","Revenue":500,"InYear":2015/01/01},{"id":12,"ProductName":"p3","Revenue":400,"InYear":2016/01/01}]
```

I want the revenues to be summed up and My output should be in

```
[{"ProductName":"P1","Revenue":2400},
```

{"ProductName":"p2","Revenue":1000},
{"ProductName":"p3","Revenue":1200}]

I have tried the following query and didnt get the result:

```
 select '[' + STUFF(( select ',{"id":' + cast(id as varchar(max)) + ',"ProductName":"' + ProductName + '"' + ',"Revenue":'
```

+ cast((sum(Revenue) as Rev) as varchar(max))  + ',"InYear":' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), InYear, 111) +'}'
        from dummyRevenueData where InYear>='2014/01/01' and InYear<='2016/01/01' 
 for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') + ']'

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use GROUP BY on first select to retrieve the data

and than use CAST to get the result in JSON format

```
SELECT CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(jsonEntry SEPARATOR ','), ']') AS jsonEntries
FROM 
  (
      SELECT '{'+ 
               '",ProductName":"' + ProductName + '"' + 
               ',"Revenue":"' + CAST(SumRevenue as varchar(SumRevenue)) + '"' + 
             '}' AS jsonEntry
      FROM
      (
           SELECT id, ProductName, SUM(Revenue) as SumRevenue 
           FROM dummyRevenueData 
           WHERE InYear>='2014/01/01' AND InYear<='2016/01/01'
           GROUP BY ProductName
      ) AS rawData

  ) AS stringData
```

dummyRevenueData:

```
id | ProductName | Revenue | InYear
---------------------------------------
2  | p1          | 700     | 2014/01/01
3  | p1          | 800     | 2015/01/01
4  | p1          | 900     | 2016/01/01
6  | P2          | 600     | 2014/01/01
7  | P2          | 200     | 2015/01/01
8  | P2          | 400     | 2016/01/01
10 | p3          | 100     | 2014/01/01
11 | p3          | 500     | 2015/01/01
12 | p3          | 400     | 2016/01/01
```

rawData:

```
ProductName | SumRevenue
------------------------
p1          | 2400
P2          | 1200
p3          | 1000
```

stringData :

```
jsonEntry
------------------------------------
{"ProductName":"p1","Revenue":"2400"}
{"ProductName":"P2","Revenue":"1200"}
{"ProductName":"p3","Revenue":"1000"}
```

jsonEntries:

```
[{"ProductName":"p1","Revenue":"2400"},{"ProductName":"P2","Revenue":"1200"},{"ProductName":"p3","Revenue":"1000"}]
```

add ProductId in dummyRevenueData, this way you can group by ProductId